# What does it mean that ranks from a Headband of Vast Intelligence don't stack with yours?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, skills

> Headband of Vast Intelligence
>
> The headband grants the wearer an enhancement bonus to Intelligence of +2, +4, or +6. Treat this as a temporary ability bonus for the first 24 hours the headband is worn. A headband of vast intelligence has one skill associated with it per +2 bonus it grants. After being worn for 24 hours, the headband grants a number of skill ranks in those skills equal to the wearer’s total Hit Dice. **These ranks do not stack with the ranks a creature already possesses.** These skills are chosen when the headband is created. If no skill is listed, the headband is assumed to grant skill ranks in randomly determined Knowledge skills.

What does **"These ranks do not stack with the ranks a creature already possesses."** mean? If you create the item with a skill/s you have ranks in, do you choose either the ranks in those kill/s the item provides or your ranks in those skill/s before adding bonuses and the d20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the skill ranks on that skill do not stack. Only the highest applies.

It is unlikely that your character will have more ranks than what the item grants you, so you always will replace your own skill ranks by the ranks granted by the item. But to make an example, if you have 5 ranks in linguistics at 7th level, the item will grant you 7 ranks, which will replace your 5 ranks and now you are considered as having 7 ranks on the skill.

From [Acquiring Skills](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/usingSkills.html#acquiring-skills):

> Each level, your character gains a number of skill ranks dependent upon your class plus your Intelligence modifier. Investing a rank in a skill represents a measure of training in that skill. **You can never have more ranks in a skill than your total number of Hit Dice**.

With that said, the item will always grant you the maximum possible skill ranks on the skill.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver Comments are not for asking new questions.